# Need help solving a problem with an array

Tags: c, arrays, cycle

**Task:** Calculate the 25 values of the function y = ax'2 + bx + c on the interval [e, f], save them in the array Y and find the minimum and maximum values in this array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    float Y[25];
    int i;
    int x=3,a,b,c;
    double y = a*pow(x,2)+b*x+c;

        printf("a = ", b);
        scanf("%d", &a);

        printf("b = ", a);
        scanf("%d", &b);

        printf("c = ", c);
        scanf("%d", &c);



    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
     printf("%f",y); //output results, not needed
     x++;
    }


    system("pause");
}
```

**Problems:**

- Cant understand how can I use "interval [e,f]" here
- Cant understand how to save values to array using C libraries
- Cant understand how to write/make a cycle, which will find the
  minimum and maximum values
- Finally, dont know what exactly i need to do to solve task

Comment: welcome to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) . Before posting on here , grab some basic first .

Answer (score 1):

You must first ask the user for the values of `a, b, c` or initialize those variables, and ask for the interval values of `e, f`, or initialize those variables.

Now you must calculate `double interval= (f - e)/25.0` so you have the interval.

Then you must have a loop `for (int i=0, double x=e; i<25; i++, x += interval)` and calculate each value of the function. You can choose to store the result in an array (declare one at the top) or print them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- Cant understand how can I use "interval [e,f]" here

(f-e) / 25(interval steps)

- Cant understand how to save values to array using C libraries

You need to use some form of loop to traverse the array and save the result of your calculation at every interval step. Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
// SIZE in this case 25, so you traverse from 0-24 since arrays start 0
```

- Cant understand how to write/make a cycle, which will find the minimum and maximum values

For both cases:

traverse the array with some form of loop and check every item e.g. (again) something like this: `for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`

For min:

1. Initialize a double value(key) with the first element of your array
2. Loop through your array searching for elements **smaller** than your initial key value.
3. if your array at position i is smaller than key, save `key = array[i]`;

For max:

1. Initialize a double value(key) with 0;
2. Loop through your array searching for elements **bigger** than your initial key value.
3. if your array at position i is bigger than key, save `key = array[i]`;

Finally, dont know what exactly i need to do to solve task

1. Initialize your variables(yourself or through user input)
2. Create a function that calculates `a*x^2 + b*x + c` n times for every step of your interval.
3. Create a function for min & max that loops through your array and returns the smallest/biggest value.

Thats pretty much it. I will refrain from posting code(for now), since this looks like an assignment to me and I am confident that you can write the code with the information @Paul Ogilvie & I have provided yourself. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
double y[25];
double x,a,b,c,e,f;
int i,j=0;
printf("Enter a:",&a);
scanf("%lf",&a);
printf("Enter b:",&b);
scanf("%lf",&b);
printf("Enter c:",&c);
scanf("%lf",&c);
printf("Starting Range:",&e);
scanf("%lf",&e);
printf("Ending Range:",&f);
scanf("%lf",&f);
for(i=e;i<=f;i++)
{
    y[j++]=(a*pow(i,2))+(b*i)+c;
}
printf("\nThe Maximum element in the given interval is %lf",y[j-1]);
printf("\nThe Minimum element in the given interval is %lf",y[0]);
}
```

Good LUCK!

Comment: Just change y[25] to y[number you want to work] and run the code...!